# Detect USB device attachment/detachment and send email

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I want to write a simple script that will send email to a specific address as soon as a USB device is plugged into a system or unplugged. Would someone please provide me a code snippet for this? I want to run it on different flavors of Linux where Ruby will be installed already.

Comment: You'll probably need to add a `udev` rule to do this. It can trigger the execution of a script when a device is plugged in. There are some details [here](https://sysadmincorner.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/writing-custom-udev-rules/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a new udev rule as follows. Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-my-custom-rule`, whose contents looks as follows:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", RUN+="usb_notify_admin add %b"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="usb_notify_admin remove %b"
```

Then put a script `usb_notify_admin` somewhere in the PATH:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $@ | mail -s "USB Notify Script" admin@example.com
```

Details:

- Writing udev rules: http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html
- mail man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/mail

Comment: ERROR: invalid rule '/etc/udev/rules.d/99-my-custom-rule.rules:1'
localhost udevd[381]: invalid SUBSYSTEM operation

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. One must use "==" instead of "=" for comparison.